# Mock rxjs debounce in Jasmine 2

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I have the following observable function:

```
$scope.$createObservableFunction("getInformation")
                    .debounce(300)
                    .flatMapLatest(function() {
                        return lookupService.getInformation($scope.basicDetails);
                    })
                    .subscribe(function(info) {
                        $scope.info = info;
                    });
```

I am testing this by running `$scope.getInformation();` in each test. I then want to check that the service has been called

```
it("should call the function retrieving the ABN details and new ABN details assigned", function () {
            expect(lookupService.getInformation).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.identity.basicInformation);
        });
```

This originally worked, but I have now added the debounce method. How can I mock this method using Jasmine 2.0.0? I don't want to use a settimeout/timer based approach

Comment: Angular has a fakeAsync method for testing async functions and then call tick(301) to fake 301 milliseconds passing, you could see if there is something similar for AngularJS or take a look in the source code. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/testing/src/fake_async.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but I ended up using the timer based approach.